# Should I do PCA reduction before applying Mclust()?

Tags: r, clustering, pca

I am doing some work where I am meant to apply `Mclust()` to my data set, with 50000 samples.

I previously used PCA in order to reduce the dimension, which left me with 20 principal components (from 35 initial variables).

Should I apply `Mclust` directly to my dataset or the transformed one from the pricipal components?

Comment: I am not very familiar with this, but it seems that MclustDR does dimension reduction for you.